# Why heroku fails to find the python/flask module or application?

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

my heroku app runs into application error with the following logs:

```
Starting process with command `gunicorn run:app`

Failed to find application: run
```

here is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn run:flask_app
```

run.py file

from app import create_app, db
from app.auth.models import User

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app = create_app('prod')
    with flask_app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        if not User.query.filter_by(user_name='harry').first():
            User.create_user(user='harry', email='harry@potters.com', password='secret')
    flask_app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main-method does not get executed (AFAIK) because Gunicorn is calling your script, you are not executing it as the main-file. Try moving the `flask_app` out of your main-method to the top of the file so Gunicorn can actually find it when importing your `run.py`!